# clearInterval() not working in React Native functional component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a screen component that has a `getPosition()` function called every second by an interval.

If the `stopRace()` function is called or if the user presses the physical/graphical back button, I want to clear this interval so it doesn't continue to run in the background.

To do this, I've tried to store the interval ID in the `raceUpdateInterval` state variable.

I then clear this interval using `clearInterval(raceUpdateInterval)` in the `stopRace()` function and the `cleanup()` function.

When I call the `stopRace()` function, then press back, the interval is cleared. I know this because my console logs:

```
Still Running
Still Running
Still Running
Reached cleanup function
```

However, if I press the back button, the interval does not clear. Instead my console logs:

```
Still Running
Still Running
Still Running
Reached cleanup function
Still Running
```

Followed by a memory leak warning containing the following advice:

```
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function
```

Which is exactly what I'm trying to do, but is not working for some reason beyond my comprehension.

Here is the relevant code for the component:

```
const RaceScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

    const [raceUpdateInterval, setRaceUpdateInterval] = useState(0);

    useEffect(function() {
        return function cleanup() {
            console.log('Reached cleanup function')
            clearInterval(raceUpdateInterval)
        }
      }, []);

    function getPosition(){
        console.log("Still being called")
        //get position
    }

    function startRace(){
        setRaceUpdateInterval(setInterval(getPosition, 1000))
    }

    function stopRace(){
        clearInterval(raceUpdateInterval)
    }
```

Why does the `stopRace()` function correctly clear the interval but the `cleanup()` function doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the reason your code might not have been working as it was, is that if you ran the `startRace` function more than once without stopping it in between, the interval would start up again but the interval ID would've been lost.

The main reason it failed to clear is that the raceUpdateInterval that it saw at the beginning when the useEffect with [] as a dependency array saw was: `0`. The reason why it didn't see the updated values is because useEffect creates a closure over the values at the point in which it runs (and re-runs). So you'd need to use a reference to give it access to the latest version of the raceUpdateInterval

Here's how I would modify your code to get it working properly. Instead of starting the timer in a function, use the `useEffect` to start up that side effect that way there will never be an instance where the timer fails to clean up.

I added the function to the interval using a ref because I don't know how many closure variables there are in the getPosition function. This way the positionFunctRef.current always points to the latest version of the function rather than remaining static.

```
const RaceScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [runningTimer, setRunningTimer] = useState(false);
  function getPosition() {
    console.log('Still being called');
    //get position
  }
  const positionFunctRef = useRef(getPosition);
  useEffect(() => {
    positionFunctRef.current = positionFunctRef;
  });

  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (!runningTimer) {
        return;
      }

      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        positionFunctRef.current();
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        console.log('Reached cleanup function');
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    },
    [runningTimer]
  );

  function startRace() {
    setRunningTimer(true);
  }

  function stopRace() {
    setRunningTimer(false);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillUnmount` is use for cleanup (like removing event listeners, cancel the timer etc). Say you are adding a event listener in `componentDidMount` and removing it in `componentWillUnmount` as below.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
}
```

Hook equivalent of above code will be as follows

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {});

  // returned function will be called on component unmount 
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', () => {})
  }
}, [])
```

So your better code is:

```
 useEffect(function() {
  setRaceUpdateInterval(setInterval(getPosition, 1000))
        return function cleanup() {
            console.log('Reached cleanup function')
            clearInterval(raceUpdateInterval)
        }
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't store something like an interval id in state, as re-renders occur each update. If you're functional, implement the `setInterval` with `useRef()`, if class based, use `this.interval`.

Another gotcha is calling `clearInterval()` in a functional component on the ref, instead of `.current`

heres a snippet from what i just debugged:

```
  const spinnerCount = useRef(0)
  const interval = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (withProgress && inProgress && notification == '') {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        if (spinnerCount.current >= 40) {
          clearInterval(interval.current)
          spinnerCount.current = 0
          setNotification('Something happened... Please try again.')
        } else {
          spinnerCount.current = spinnerCount.current + 1
        }
      }, 1000)
    } 
    if (notification !== '' && inProgress === false) {
      const delay = notification.length > 100 ? 6000 : 3000
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval.current)
        spinnerCount.current = 0
        setNotification('');
      }, delay);
    }
  }, [inProgress])
```

Theres a little extra in there, basically this is a disappearing notification component, that also features a progress spinner. in this case, if the component is displaying the spinner, but a success/error notification is never triggered, the spinner will auto-quit after 40 seconds. hence the interval/spinnerCount